CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long (mvn)
i am trying to setup a maven repo on local machine and after running mvn spring-boot:run the terminal pops up with an error:
> [INFO] --- spring-boot:3.1.1:run (default-cli) @ webapp ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.522 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-04-03T17:11:33+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.1.1:run (default-cli) on project webapp: Process execution failed: Cannot run program "C:\jdk-17\bin\java.exe" (in directory "D:\smartLight\Website\SmartlightWebApp"): CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException


I have tried to set the repo to a shorter path
enabled long path support for windows
done Upgrading Maven.

i am using VScode as my IDE and Java 17
